# Buddha Statue Identification

Tags: buddha

[image]

Greetings, a delivery driver crushed my statue with a giant truck. I would like help with identification so that I may replace it.

Comment: ̶I̶f̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶R̶e̶d̶d̶i̶t̶ ̶a̶c̶c̶o̶u̶n̶t̶,̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶B̶u̶d̶d̶h̶i̶s̶t̶S̶t̶a̶t̶u̶e̶s̶ ̶s̶u̶b̶r̶e̶d̶d̶i̶t̶ ̶u̶s̶u̶a̶l̶l̶y̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶p̶r̶e̶t̶t̶y̶ ̶g̶o̶o̶d̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶i̶d̶e̶n̶t̶i̶f̶i̶c̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶.̶ Oh I see you already posted there — don't forget a picture, though!

Answer (score 3):

I cannot be definitive but I guess it is a Angkor/Khmer/Cambodia Buddha or Avalokitesvara, as found in the many Google images [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=avalokitesvara+Angkor+&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjo77jKv4X_AhX01XMBHarUBE4Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=avalokitesvara+Angkor+&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1CRCFiRCGDTDmgAcAB4AIABogKIAfMDkgEDMi0ymAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=p5NpZKiAPfSrz7sPqqmT8AQ&bih=629&biw=1366), [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=Khmer+buddha+statue&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiwu6DlvoX_AhVK0nMBHY6GAFcQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=Khmer+buddha+statue&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1C8B1i8B2DdCWgAcAB4AIABtgGIAekCkgEDMC4ymAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=05JpZPCFMMqkz7sPjo2CuAU&bih=629&biw=1366) & [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=avalokitesvara+Khmer&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjm34vqvoX_AhXN73MBHS8UC6wQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=avalokitesvara+Khmer&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1AAWABg9QJoAHAAeACAAcUBiAHFAZIBAzAuMZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=3ZJpZKb9OM3fz7sPr6is4Ao&bih=629&biw=1366). Some similar statues are [here](https://www.hdasianart.com/products/buddha-statue-antique-khmer-style-bronze-enlightenment-angkor-wat-buddha-statue-52cm-21-quot?shpxid=04eecd61-1e6c-4a34-a39e-db3a996780de) & [here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/284229584076).